# JavaScript - less than one week old

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a Date is less than 1 week old. It should return true for one week in time, or false if it is older.

Comment: This isn't a request site

Comment: Could you share where you're stuck instead of expecting someone to write the code for you?

Comment: ` if(lessThan1WeekOld(date)) {} ` then just write your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A week in milliseconds is `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7`.

You can then check whether a date is less than a week old by comparing the date to a week old date like so:

`return date > Date.now() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)`